# How to convert the UserControl values to NameValueCollectionw?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages, namevaluecollection

I have a Web Application in Asp.Net WebForm.

On a web page there are two tabs `Student1` and `Student2` and both the tab contain the same form which has two TextBox fields FirstName and LastName.

Now let us suppose, I am currently on the `Student1` tab and the value of `FirstName` and `LastName` is FirstOne and LastOne respectively. Now, I click on `Student2` Tab, then the `Student1` form is automatically submitted and the value of `FirstName` and `LastName`
form `Student1` Tab is saving in a session.

```
var student1DataCollection= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form; //DataTye is NameValueCollection

Session["Student1"] = student1DataCollection;
```

So, Whenever I come back to `Student1` the same value of the `FirstName` and `SecondName` is displayed in the form. This works similarly for `Student2` Tab.

But now my requirement is to save the value of the form manually.

```
((TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("FirstName")).Text = "TestFirstName"
((TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("LastName")).Text = 
"TestLastName"
```

As we see I have assigned values for `FirstName` and `LastName` manually. Now I need to save this value of `FirstName` and `LastName` in `Session["Student1"]` in the form of NameValueCollection so that whenever I go to `Student1` Tab. The value is displayed

How Can I convert this value to `NameValueCollection`?

Comment: What kind of tab control you using here? There is not  default tab control from the tool box, so it not at all clear what kind of tab you talking about? there are good 100 or so different tab controls out in the big internet, and they all often work different. Most tab control examples don't  post-back the page when you select a different tab. Or do you mean that you have two browser pages open?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Let's just forget about the Tab. What I just need is to save the value of 
   of FisrtName and LastName in a session. Suppose the value of firstname is firstname1 and the value of lastName is lastname1 for Student1 and similarly the value of firstname is firstname2 and the value of lastName is lastName2 for Student2. Now when the form is loaded it checks the a variable which determined either it is student1 or student2, if it is student1 then the value of firstname and last name should be firstname1 and lastname1 in the form , same goes for student2.